# Why date picker does not appear?

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to show calender when user click on input field, 
can some one tell me why this script doesn't execute ?

```
<input type="text" id="dob"/>
```

here is the script

```
 $("#dob").click(function(){    

    alert("here");
    $("#dob").datepicker();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zncSh/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$("#dob").datepicker();` when the page loads, not when you click on the input box. When you call `.datepicker()` when the page loads, JQuery will automatically assign all the relevant event handlers to the input box to show the picker. So do this in your JQuery instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#dob").datepicker();
});
```